# discord.js v12 Userinfo command works when user isn't mentioned or when user id is given

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a userinfo command which works on mentioning the user. Here is the code:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('+ui')) {
        const args = message.content.slice(4).trim().split(/ +/g);
        const member = message.mentions.members.first();

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${member.displayName}'s Information`)
            .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL({
                dynamic: true
            }))
            .addField('User', member, true)
            .addField('Discriminator', `\`#${member.user.discriminator}\``, true)
            .addField('ID', `\`${member.id}\``, true)
            .addField('Status', statuses[member.presence.status], true)
            .addField('Bot', `\`${member.user.bot}\``, true)
            .addField('Color Role', member.roles.color || '`None`', true)
            .addField('Highest Role', member.roles.highest, true)
            .addField('Joined server on', `\`${moment(member.joinedAt).format('MMM DD YYYY')}\``, true)
            .addField('Joined Discord on', `\`${moment(member.user.createdAt).format('MMM DD YYYY')}\``, true)
            .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL({
                dynamic: true
            }))
            .setTimestamp()
            .setColor(member.displayHexColor);
        if (activities.length > 0) embed.setDescription(activities.join('\n'));
        if (customStatus) embed.spliceFields(0, 0, {
            name: 'Custom Status',
            value: customStatus
        });
        if (userFlags.length > 0) embed.addField('Badges', userFlags.map(flag => flags[flag]).join('\n'));
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
});
```

However, this only works when the message sent is `+ui @User`. However, if I want my own userinfo I need to use +ui `@mention` where I mention myself.

How can I make the bot send the message author's output when no mentions are given and userinfo if a user's id is given instead of mention.

Sorry for any kind of misunderstanding caused by the question. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a fallback value when `message.mentions.members.first()` gives you undefined.

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member
```